# Save Camera Photo To File Location - Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my app, I allow the user to **take** a photo with the **camera**. When *didFinishPickingMedia* executes, I want to save the photo to the **FILE LOCATION** (url... ***modelController.saveLocation***) the user previously selected earlier in the app. The file location may be a folder in File Directory, Dropbox, etc. I can't seem to figure out how to do this, despite my reading efforts online. The other tutorials seem to be taking a photo that's in the *assets* folder and saving it somewhere, not a photo that was **just taken**.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work. The code in the catch statement is called due to some error.

```
let url = modelController.saveLocation[0].appendingPathComponent("\(saveLocationName.description).jpg")
        if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.00) {
            do {
                try data.write(to: url)
            } catch {
                print("Unable to write image data to disk")
                selectNewFileLocation()
            }
            
        }
```

Please explain your answers with code. It's probably a really simple solution, but I'm a rookie. Thanks for your help ahead of time!

Comment: Inside the `catch` block, can you do `print("Unable to write image data to disk: \(error)")`? That will print out the error.

Comment: you can't save file anywhere you want... there are certain permissions etc. Check if `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)` works. If so, the problem is not with _how_ you are saving, but with _where_ you are saving

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, I think you have came up with an answer. But this is for people encounter this problem. For some reasons, after I changed the format to **png** format instead of **jpeg**, it works, but after using the format **jpeg** again, it works too. I don't really know why, cause now I can't reproduce this problem.

```
let url = modelController.saveLocation[0].appendingPathComponent("\(saveLocationName.description).png")
    if let data = image.pngData() {
        do {
            try data.write(to: url)
        } catch {
            print("Unable to write image data to disk")
            selectNewFileLocation()
        }
        
    }
```